# Autocomplete not Working in ASP.NET Core 5 Razor Tag Helper in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, omnisharp

I'm experiencing issues with Visual Studio Code autocomplete inside Razor Pages (.cshtml) with ASP.NET Core 5. The autocomplete works only for a few old projects. For new ASP.NET Core 5 projects, it does not work. I already tried to restart OmniSharp, reinstall VS Code and extensions, but nothing solved the problem. I'm a programming teacher and my students are facing the same issue. We are using the latest version of VS Code and .NET Core 5 stable release. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, Jeremy, I did that, but the issue remains. The problem seems to be with OmniSharp. It was not loading the project correctly. So, I reloaded the project using Shift + Ctrl + P -> OmniSharp: Select Project… This action forces OmniSharp to reload the project and make code complete works again. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tag Helpers must be referenced somewhere, either directly in the file you are editing or in a _ViewImports.cshtml file. Here is an example of referencing Microsoft's Tag Helpers.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0#importing-shared-directives